# send data to HTTP url without variable in php

Tags: php, http

I saw on some sites data is sending within HTTP URL without passing any variable .
For e.g. http://example.com/page/1/
instead of 
http://example.com?page=1
how its possible ? 
As no of pages is unknown we cant create folder for each page no and index file within that folder.
How can i achieve it?

Comment: Try .haccess with URL Rewriting

Comment: 1. Format problem in your question ..."For e.g. instead of how its possible"
2: as Koen said, URL rewriting with .htaccess (you missed a T koen :P)

Comment: thank you koen and twinfriends its what i was looking for. 1 more question is there any impact on Search engine rank by rewritting the url?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.htaccess` for this.
First, get the `page` parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+)\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /page/%1/? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Then, you want the matching parameters displayed in the new URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/?$ /page.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```